# Create temporary aliases in zshrc

Tags: zsh, bash

Is there a way to create an temporary aliases, mainly to cut down typing dir paths, especially those not used as often to warrant adding to .bash_aliases?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just type one in.

```
94 $ alias hello='echo hello'
95 $ hello
hello
```

Answer (score 3):

You can type

```
long=~/long/path/to/a/directory
```

and use it as

```
cd ~long
```

(just add tilde to the beginning).

You will also see "~long" in your prompt instead of the full path.

Comment: I did not knew about it (guess it is controlled by some option and can be turned off). Why don't you use `$long` instead? `$` is easier to type and you can do some smart things like `$long:s/foo/bar/`.

Comment: If you use `cd $long` the path in prompt isn't shortened. I don't know if there are other reasons to use ~ instead of $.

Comment: Missed this, though most of time I don't care.